# How to call a variable from another file in php?

Tags: php

I have a `php code` as shown below in which I want to call a variable from another file in php. `$text_config` variable is present inside `text_global.php` file. At `Line#A`, I am getting the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: text_config in ./text/index.php on line A
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'text_global.php';

class HomePage extends TemplatePage {
    protected function body () {
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ABC</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <fieldset>
                <option value="<?= $type; ?>" <?=$DEFAULT_VALUE; ?>>
                    <?= $text_config->getName($type); ?>   <!-- Line A -->
                </option>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <?php } } ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php
$page = new HomePage;
$page->generatePage();
?>
```

Comment: Why not use `include`? Where did you define `$text_config`? Also, I would assume this variable is not available in that method - try to use `global $text_config`, even if this is a pretty bad idea

Comment: @NicoHaase because `require` is a little more robust, perhaps? But yes obviously we need to see how/where the variable is defined. Presumably it's gone out of scope, probably as you say because they're trying to access it inside a class where it's not defined.

Comment: *"$text_config variable is present inside text_global.php file"* - The error would suggest otherwise.  Can you demonstrate?

Comment: Add `global $text_config;` under `protected function body () {`..

Comment: First time I see a class method break out of PHP to blurt out HTML. I did not even imagine. (And yes this is obviously an out of scope error.) Pooling output into variable(s) that are returned from methods, and then compiling and outputting only when all is said and done, is a good way to avoid the gremlin onslaught. A touch of architecture on top of that, even including a strategy to get variables to where they belong without globals, and things suddenly become quite a bit more maintainable.

Comment: Also just to note the next obvious, it's not only `$text_config` that's out of scope. Also `$DEFAULT_VALUE` and `$type` are out of scope. These sorts of things _could_ be fed in through a constructor when instantiating a class. Classes can have properties and a constructor. They're not just a means for grouping functions.